# Can't get getCustomer() in custom event

Tags: magento2, event-observer, customer

If I observe `customer_save_after` event I can get information about the customer with `$customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();`.

However, if dispatching my custom event instead of `customer_save_after` I get

```
Error: Call to a member function getDataModel() on null
```

when I try to get it like `$customerData = $customer->getDataModel();`

I think this is because I can't even get `getCustomer()` in an custom event.

Is there anything I could do to get the same data as from `customer_save_after`?

Edit: custom dispatch

```
public function afterAddCustomer()
    {
        $this->eventManager->dispatch(
            'myname_customer_save_after',
            ['block' => $this]
        );
    }
```

Edit2: Changed the dispatcher but now I get

```
Error: Call to undefined method Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\EventCompanyAccount::getDataModel()
```

I think `getDataModel()` method can be found in `\Magento\Customer\Model\Data\AttributeMetadata.php` but extending my class does not fix the error.

Comment: Please add the custom code of your custom event dispatching.

Comment: Edited above @DianaBotean

Answer (score 0):

Either you fix the custom dispatcher like:

```
public function afterAddCustomer()
{
    $this->eventManager->dispatch(
        'myname_customer_save_after',
        ['customer' => $this]
    );
}
```

OR
Use the following code in the listener:

```
$observer->getEvent()->getBlock()
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to fix the first error but now I get Error: Call to undefined method (see edit2 above). How to fix this? Thanks